# Cross platform Sequential GUID

Tags: c#, linux, mono, guid

I'm in the process of making one of my distributed c# .net libraries cross platform so I can deploy it to linux via mono and have come across an issue: I use a sequential GUID for generating ID's like this:

```
[DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);
```

This is obviously only good on a Windows platform.

Should I just forget about the sequential guid creation bit on linux and use a random guid? or does anyone have any suggestions on how I can replace the DllImport with something more appropriate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NHibernate has managed code to do this in the [GuidCombGenerator](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/GuidCombGenerator.cs).